Software for converting large numbers of TTAs to large numbers of FLACs?
I've got about 80GB of TTA files with their respective CUEs on my hard drive right now, and I'd like to be able to convert them all to FLAC files for easier listening. However, I've tried batchConverter, and it returns nothing but errors. Are there other programs out there for this? Each TTA contains several music tracks.

My suggestion would be ffmpeg, a terminal program.

I see. Is it the only one that can do this? I'm seeing the possibility of it chopping up the files improperly in one Google search.

Welcome citrus!  Do you have any OS or gratis/price preference for recommendations?  If so, please add them to you question and tags.  Thanks, and again, welcome!

As mentioned by @EndAntisemiticHate, do you have a preferred OS? Needs to be GUI? How many files?
